# TypeLoadException after upgrading to SignalR 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr-hub

I am getting the following error message after upgrading to SignalR 2.0

```
[TypeLoadException: Could not load type &#39;Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.IWebSocketRequest&#39; from assembly &#39;Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35&#39;.]
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.CallHandler.Invoke(IDictionary`2 environment) +0
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.Handlers.HubDispatcherHandler.Invoke(IDictionary`2 environment) +369
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinCallContext.Execute() +333
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object extraData) +713
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.Infrastructure.ErrorState.Rethrow() +62
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallContextAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +271
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +45
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously) +288
```

I drilled down in the component exdplorer and indeed IWebSocketRequest is no longer there. It looks like I need to replace some binding handler, but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read here to learn about potential issues with updating to 2.0 http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/upgrading-signalr-1x-projects-to-20.